# Any idea why I need to cast an integer literal to (int) here?

Tags: java, syntax, casting

In the following example

```
int i = -128;
Integer i2 = (Integer) i; // compiles

Integer i3 = (Integer) -128; /*** Doesn't compile ***/

Integer i4 = (Integer) (int) -128; // compiles
Integer i4 = -128; // compiles
Integer i5 = (int) -128; // compiles
Integer i6 = (Integer) (-128); // compiles
Integer i7 = (Integer) 0-128; // compiles
```

I can't cast `-128` with `(Integer)` but I can cast `(int) -128`.

I always thought `-128` was of `int` type and casting it with `(int)` should be redundant.

The error on the line with `i3` is

```
cannot find symbol variable Integer
```

I tried this with Java 6 update 29 and Java 7 update 1.

EDIT: You get the same behavior with `+128` instead of `-128`.  It does appear to be confusion between unary and binary operators.

Comment: what's your compiler? `Integer i = -128;` this should compile, though.

Comment: wierd, `Integer i3 = (Integer) (-128);` complies though.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, Peter, unary symbols (+-) have right to left associativity and plus, minus are left to right. The effect of -128 would be the same as +128 and putting 0 in front should fix, i.e. 0-128 or 0+128. (cant test atm but I bet it will)

Comment: Good question! I'd personally like to see a JLS reference for the resolution of unary/binary operators and when a cast is treated as an expression. Otherwise, it might be possible that other compilers do not consider it an error!

Comment: Also FYI the error I get in my IDE is `Expression expected` where the `Integer` is.

Comment: @peter just a doubt. why do u need to cast in java 6 and 7. I thought the **autoboxing** feature in java 6 and 7 should take care of that. I havent tried the code, so i might be wrong.

Comment: You do know that an `Integer` is not the same as an `int`?

Comment: What about `new Integer(-128)`?

Comment: When java already provide feature of the auto boxing and un-boxing why do we even need to type-cast? Is there specific need for this ?

Comment: @neo, In the example above, its not needed but in other example it makes a difference e.g. `-128 == -128` is true but `(Integer) -128 == (Integer) -128` is false. A more complex example is http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/omg-using-triple-cast.html

Comment: Not sure how you tested but i got true for  System.out.println(-128==-128);
System.out.println((Integer)(-128)==-128);
System.out.println((Integer)(-128)==(Integer)(-128));
//System.out.println((Integer)-128==-128); // Not allowed or compiled.

Comment: I always found it weird that **int Integer = 10;** compiles. Makes sense but just weird: **int Integer = 10; Integer i3 = (Integer) -128; System.out.println(i3);**

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The compiler tries to subtract `128` from `(Integer)` instead of casting `-128` to `Integer`. Add `()` to fix it

```
Integer i3 = (Integer) -128; // doesn't compile
Integer i3 = (Integer) (-128); // compiles
```

According to BoltClock in the comments the cast to  `int` works as intended, because it is a reserved word and therefore can't be interpreted as an identifier, which makes sense to me.

And Bringer128 found the JLS Reference [15.16](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#238146).

```
 CastExpression:
    ( PrimitiveType Dimsopt ) UnaryExpression
    ( ReferenceType ) UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus
```

As you can see, casting to a primitive type requires any `UnaryExpression`, whereas casting to a reference type requires a `UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus`. These are defined just before the CastExpression at [JLS 15.15](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.15).

Comment: I think it's because `int` is a keyword in Java, but `Integer` is not. Since `int` is a keyword, you can't use it as an identifier for a variable or a class, leaving the only possibility left for it to be a typecast. That'd explain it.

Comment: @BoltClock Incorporated your comment in the answer.

Comment: To make this an even more stellar answer, do you want to add my link to the JLS?

Comment: An interesting (to me) wrinkle on this issue is how we solve the analogous problem in C#, which also has an ambiguity in the grammar between "parenthesized expression as an operand to binary subtraction operator" and "cast operator where the right operand of the cast is a unary minus expression". See section 7.7.6 of the C# specification for a detailed description of the heuristics we use to try and be smart about resolving the amgiguity.

Comment: It's crap like this that makes me glad we don't have operator overloading in Java...  This could get significantly more complicated in no-time

Comment: @BillK Why do you say that? The C# spec doesn't refer to operator overloading in section 7.7.6, so it wasn't an issue for them.

Comment: This grammar definition was perfectly fine and free of ambiguities before autoboxing was introduced. I'd consider it as one of the less serious deficiencies of autoboxing in comparision to sudden NullPoniterExceptions and inconsistent equality due to Integer object caching.

Comment: Thank you @Mystical, all the other upvoters, and the other contributors to this answer.

Answer (score 48):

I found the JLS reference. [15.16](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#238146).

```
 CastExpression:
    ( PrimitiveType Dimsopt ) UnaryExpression
    ( ReferenceType ) UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus
```

As you can see, casting to a primitive type requires any `UnaryExpression`, whereas casting to a reference type requires a `UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus`. These are defined just before the CastExpression at [JLS 15.15](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.15).

You need to either change the cast to a primitive type:

```
... (int) -128;
```

Or you can change the expression to the right of the cast to a non-plus-minus unary expression:

```
... (Integer) (-128);  // Either
... (Integer) 0 - 128; // Or
```

Answer (score 11):

The compiler interprets the `-` as the two-arg minus operator, i.e. it's trying to subtract 128 from some other number named `Integer`, but there's no such variable in scope.

This compiles:

```
Integer i3 = (Integer) (-128)
```

Comment: You could add a comment on why `(int)` makes a difference.

Comment: It's due to the autoboxing, no?

Answer (score 8):

This may have to do with syntax parsing. Notice that

```
Integer i4 = (Integer) (-128);
```

works just fine.

In general, you should not cast to Integer class. This involves something called auto-boxing, and can cause some subtle errors in your code.
The prefered method of doing what you want is:

```
Integer i6 = Integer.valueOf(-128)
```

Comment: cast to Integer is exactly synthetic sugar for valueOf.

Comment: yes, but sometimes the synthetic sugar fails in subtle ways. I've had some hard to track down null pointer exceptions in large applications due to auto-boxing. We went as far as treating auto-boxing as errors in order to save headaches in the future. Magic is nice, but when it fails, heads hurt. I find it is better to be explicit and save yourself the headaches.

Comment: NPE are b1tch w/ outboxing, true. Esp cases like  `for (int i in Collection<Integer>)` b/c the NPE is at absolutely unexpected location. I actually do not use Integer w/ autoboxing since the cache range is small (albeit it can be increased w/ XX option) but have a class called IntegerProvider (since 1.1) to do the very same stuff. Using Map (any from java.util) Integer->Anything is usually a performance hit unless it's used for trivial cases and almost always there is a better solution.

Comment: Casting int to Integer can *never* cause any errors, except heap overflow, perhaps. The inverse is not true, though.

Comment: @MattBall, I dont quite get it, synthetic sugar is used widely: http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4400 and synthetic sounds better to me.

Answer (score 8):

It's parsing it as `Integer <minus operator> 128` and not finding the variable `Integer`. You'll need to wrap the `-128` in brackets:

```
Integer i3 = (Integer) (-128);  // compiles
```

Comment: I've awarded +1 to all other answers cos they're all correct too :)

Answer (score 6):

```
Integer i3 = (Integer) (-128);
```

The problem is the `-` The compiler sees it as an operator.

Answer (score 5):

Line 3 is interpreted like you're trying to deduct 128 from the expression in the parenthesis and the expression in the parenthesis is not and expression of type int (It treats the '-' as a '-' operator). If you change the expression to:

```
Integer i3 = (Integer) (-128);
```

then the compiler will understand the '-' is the unary minus that indicates a negative integer.

Answer (score 2):

The C# compiler has the same behaviour. It gives a better hint why it fails to compile though:

> To cast a negative value, you must enclose the value in parentheses