# Type casting in Java

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any idea why I need to cast an integer literal to (int) here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900198/any-idea-why-i-need-to-cast-an-integer-literal-to-int-here)

```
package typecastingpkg;

public class Main
{        
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       byte a=10;
       Integer b=(int)-a;
       System.out.println(b);

       int x=25;
       Integer c=(Integer)(-x); // If the pair of brackets around -x are dropped, a compile-time error is issued - illegal start of type.
       System.out.println(c);

       Integer d=(int)-a;     //Compiles fine. Why does this not require a pair of braces around -a?
       System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

In this code, while casting of `-x` of primitive type `int` to a wrapper type `Integer`, a compile-time error is produced: `illegal start of type`.

```
Integer c=(Integer)-x;
```

It requires a pair of braces around `-x` like `Integer c=(Integer)(-x);`

The following expression however compiles fine.

```
Integer d=(int)-a;
```

Why does this one not require a pair of braces around `-a` as in the preceding expression?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler thinks that, in the expression `(Integer)-x`, you are trying to subtract `x` from a variable called `Integer`, hence the error since no such variable is defined. `(int)-x` works because `int` is a reserved keyword for a primitive type and cannot be used as a variable name, so the compiler can deduce that you are trying to cast, not subtract.

Comment: +1 because addition of "int Integer=25; " gave me 0 without compiler warning :D

Comment: The error doesn't have to do with no such variable being defined. It has to do with the grammar not accepting unary operators when reference types are used in the cast expression.

Comment: @VivinPaliath If you define a variable called `Integer` the program will compile: e.g. `int Integer = 2; int x = 1; Integer n = (Integer)-x;`. Print `n` to see that `(Integer)-x` subtracts and does not cast.

Comment: @A.R.S. That's not the same thing. The reason that the second example works is not the reason that the first example breaks. You're comparing apples to oranges because those two examples do two different things (casting vs. subtraction). The actual reason is that you cannot cast a unary expression if you are using a reference type. It only works for primitive types.

Comment: @VivinPaliath And that's because reference type names can be used as identifiers while primitive type names cannot be, wouldn't you agree? Sorry - not trying to continuously argue with you.

Comment: @A.R.S. No worries. I think your answer is essentially right. :) I was only arguing about the error that shows up. If the compiler thought that it was an identifier, it would complain with an "unknown identifier" error.

Answer (score 5):

The answer can be found by [examining Java's grammar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16):

```
CastExpression:
    ( PrimitiveType ) UnaryExpression
    ( ReferenceType ) UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus
```

Which tells you that you can use a cast expression like `(int) -x;` because `int` is a primitive type and so you can have a unary expression that follows it. However, if you use an object then that's a `ReferenceType` and the only thing that follows a `ReferenceType` is [`UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15), which doesn't include things like `-x` or `+x`:

```
UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus:
    PostfixExpression
    ~ UnaryExpression
    ! UnaryExpression
    CastExpression
```

The reason for this prohibition is that `Integer` by itself could be interpreted as an identifier, which leads to ambiguity. `int` cannot be interpreted as an identified because it is a reserved word. To resolve this ambiguity, you would have to wrap the unary expression in parenthesis.

Comment: nice. but why did they allow `(Integer)~a` but not `(Integer)-a`

Comment: probably because `~` cannot be used as binary op, like +/-

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast primitive to class and vice versa.

You can cast primitives to other primitives. In this case value precision can be lost. For example if you are casting long to int.

You can also cast object to other type.

Actually assignment of primitive wrapper types to primitives is allowed since java 1.5 by autoboxing and can confuse. This is just a compiler sugar. When you say

`Integer a = 5;` compiler translates it to `Integer a = new Integer(5);`

If you say then

`int b = a;` you really say `int b = a.intValue();`

Unfortunately operators like +, - etc are not working with primitive wrappers. Only primitives support them. So, you cannot say `-a`. You must say `(-1)*a.intValue()`. Now this value can be assigned to either int or Integer variable: autoboxing will do the job.

Comment: Sure you can -- `int a = 1; Integer b = (Integer)a;` compiles fine.

Comment: `Integer c=(Integer)(-x);` Is that a cast or an autoboxing?

Comment: @A.R.S.: That compiles but don't you think it's a case of autoboxing. Because it doesn't make sense being a able to cast a primitive value to reference type. What if it was some other class instead of Integer.